# simple_form validation with non-ActiveRecord model not working right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, validation

I'm using simple_form with a vanilla Ruby model that's not stored in the database. It's a helper model that interacts with a model that is in the db. I'm able to use `simple_form_for` with a symbol rather than an instance (`simple_form_for :vanilla_model`), but running into a problem with client-side validation (HTML5 `required` attribute).

My form has a select box and some radio-buttons. I go ahead and choose an option in each, and click 'submit'. Rather than submitting the form, the browser highlights (doesn't select, just focuses) the first radio-button, as it would if I'd failed to make a choice.

I can get around this by disabling the `required` attribute, but I'd actually like to use it. Here's my view:

```
= simple_form_for(:my_model, url: my_path, method: :post) do |f|
  = f.input_field :number, collection: numbers
  = f.input_field :color, collection: colors, as: :radio_buttons
  = f.button :submit
```

and the generated HTML

```
<form action="/my/path" class="simple_form my_model" method="post">
  <div>
    ... utf8 & authenticity token ...
  </div>

  <select class="select required" id="my_model_number" name="my_model[number]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>

  <span class="radio">
    <input class="radio_buttons required" id="my_model_color_red" name="my_model[color]" type="radio" value="red" />
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="my_model_color_red">Red</label>
  </span>
  <span class="radio">
    <input class="radio_buttons required" id="my_model_color_blue" name="my_model[color]" type="radio" value="blue" />
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="my_model_color_blue">Blue</label>
  </span>

  <input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Can someone point out what I'm missing here? Should I just give up on trying to take advantage of the HTML5 validation and use jQuery? I'm using jQuery for some other parts of the page, so I could go that route, but I'd like to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally bad practice to rely on HTML 5 validations because many browsers do not support them.  Why not add the validations to your model to do it the rails way?

```
validates :color, inclusion: {in: ["red", "blue"]}
```

Comment: `validates` isn't available to my model, since it's a plain Ruby model, not inheriting from any of the Rails classes/modules. I'd like to keep this model pretty lightweight. However, your point about relying on HTML5 validations is well-taken. I might as well validate with jQuery since I'm using it elsewhere anyway. Thanks

Comment: http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/            here is a link which explains how to make a form-backing service object without all the overhead of active record.

Comment: That pivotallabs article is a great read. It filled in some of the details I was lacking.